# Adding a context variable with AJAX in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have a select form that needs to be populated through AJAX. Consider this simple example:

**templates/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="elements">
</select>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-something/5',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#elements').html(msg)
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/get-something/<int:n>')
def get_something(n):
    result = ''
    for i in xrange(n):
        result += "<option value='%s'>%s</option>\n" % (i, i)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

That **works just fine** and is what I did. But, I was wondering if there exists another (better?) way.

For instance, I'd prefer having a context variable to better separate the view from the controller. Something like this:

**app.modified.py**

```
@app.route('/get-something/<int:n>')
def get_something(n):
    return dict(elements=xrange(n))
```

**templates/index.modified.html**

```
<select id="elements">
    {% for elem in elements %}
        <option value='{{ elem }}'>{{ elem }}</option>\n
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Unfortunately, that does **not** work. It says, *'dict' object is not callable*.

Any help please? Is this even possible? Notice that I don't want to reload the page, I want the same behavior that you get in the AJAX example.

Answer (score 1):

Using index.modified, you need to do something like this:

```
return render_template('index.modified.html',
                       elements=your_dictionary)
```

Not trying to return a dictionary (which is why you are getting that error).  See http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates fore more examples

Comment: That would reload tthe page. I don't want that.

Comment: Then you should send Json not html, and parse using JavaScript to construct the select. Use return json.dumps(thedictionary) to send back the dictionary of elements.  I won't change the answer as the problem stated had an issue with templating.

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning `render_template('index.modified.html', elements=xrange(n))` since you want the html.

`render_template` returns a string which you can then encode as JSON. Ex:

```
data = render_template('index.modified.html', elements=xrange(n))
return json.dumps({'data': data})
```